# Windows CE: Debug Output: Failed on waiting multiple events

Tags: client-server, windows-ce

i use for an old device(client) (ARMV4I-architecture) VS2008 to develop a server-client application with a GUI(MFC). OS is WindowsCE. The communication works with the Server, but in the Debug-Mode it appears the following text in the output-window:

*"Error: failed on waiting multiple events."*

If i run only the GUI without network-connection, the text not appears.

My first question is: Could this issue run into communication disruption?

I have read some articles suggesting to use Shutdown( 2 ), AsyncSelect(0) before closing a socket (CSockets/CAsyncSocket). But this does not solve this issue.
The second question is:
Are other possibilities known to solve this problem?

Thx in advance

Comment: The only way to know is to understand when and where in your code this message is generated. Looks like an application-generated error message, so searching inside the code would be the first way to discover more.

Comment: The error message is not code i have written. Some sites write about this message but without solution.